# Can't access public IP of AKS ingress

Tags: azure, nginx, networking, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

im struggling to get my AKS cluster to work.
I can't access my public IP for my service (using nginx-ingress-controller )
I triess the azure load balancer ingress but that wasnt working either
I created a static public IP in my azure console and assigned it to my nginx ingress conrtoller - that IP doesn't work either
I tried also deleting the kube-proxy pods, as some people complained that these wouldn't update after recreating their ingress, so they had to recreated by deleting them.
It's not an issue of no ingress rules being setup, because I'm getting a connection Time out (IP can't even be reached) rather than a 404 error

Here's my ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.app
      secretName: tls
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Here's my services

`$ kubectl get svc -A`

```
default       kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>         443/TCP                         2d1h
default       app                                  LoadBalancer   10.0.85.118    20.81.3.210    8080:30578/TCP,6565:31233/TCP   171m
ingress       ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.21.143    20.121.107.7   80:31325/TCP,443:31584/TCP      18m
```

I can reach my app at the public IP for the service (load balancer config)

http://20.81.3.210:8080 - 401 API error, as expected

but not at the ingress https://20.121.107.7 - connection timeout

---

I heard sometimes the kube proxies fail to update after setting up an ingress, so I tried deleting the kube-proxy pods (and letting them re-create) but that didn't fix anything.

Also tried assigning the ingress to a manually created public-IP address (assigned by the Azure platform) but that didn't help either

Comment: Can you please check if the  NSG rules are added or not.This error usually occurs when there are no Allow inbound rules from Internet to LoadBalancer, so DenyAllInbound will block the traffic.
Could you please create appropriate NSG rules to allow inbound rules from Internet.
If it does not work, kindly provide some additonal information around the configuration of NSGs.

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju Shouldn't such inbound rules be automatically created?

Comment: Please check if they are present by default, If not we may have to create them.

Comment: HI Tobi, did this recommendation resolve the issue for you?  I have a similar problem and i see two rules on the nsg (port 80 & 443) from Internet to the ip address.  However, i don't see Internet to Loadbalancer rule

Comment: @ossentoo no it didn't solve it. I've been stuck on this for like a week. I believe I found the issue, but its still very temparametnal, its to do with the health probes of azure. If they fail to probe your service, azure will shut off all connection to your ingress public IP (causing time outs)

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju that didn't help.

Comment: understood.  So you have managed to get at least some traffic to a pod?  Good for you.   i've been on my problem for a couple of days. let me check out docs on health probes, thanks.

Comment: Something i have found very helpful is the Network Watcher (in the Azure portal). it is showing me where the issues might be (at least from a networking perspective).  Go to the NSG diagnostic blade.

Comment: @ossentoo As long as your probes are working, you should be able to get traffic fine. (when you install the controller, you can set an annotation that specifies where you want Azure to probe). My problem is I have a GRPC service along-side a a HTTP service, and getting the probes to work for both is finicky

Comment: @ossentoo did you get yours working

Comment: finally i did yes.  Fortunately i was able to raise an MS support request.  It turns out that there was an nsg setup (not the aks one), with a deny all rule, that was blocking traffic.  So the cluster was setup correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tobi,

Check out this github issue: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2903

If you are running latest clstuer 1.24, you might want to downgrade to 1.23 for now because yes, there is an issue with the health probes and Azure cluster.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much, I didn't figure out that it was a bug with the kubernetes version. I tried 1.23 and the health probes worked perfectly!

Comment: I can't believe I was stuck on this for so long

Comment: i know.  Couldn't believe myself as well that a bug with the product caused me to spend quite a bit of unnecessary time on this.  :-(.  Anyway, i'm glad you got it resolved.